# mariadb collate error disabling mysqldump

Tags: mariadb, collation

I want to do a mysqldump but get an error like

mysqldump: Got error: 1273: "Unknown collation '#246' in table 'yoast_seo_links' definition" when using LOCK TABLES

when I login to Mariadb and and try 
 select * from yoast_seo_links;
ERROR 1273 (HY000): Unknown collation '#246' in table 'yoast_seo_links' definition

How can I dump data? 
I already gone through a lot of forums but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SHOW COLLATION LIKE 'utf8mb4%';
+------------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+
| Collation              | Charset | Id  | Default | Compiled | Sortlen |
+------------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+
| utf8mb4_general_ci     | utf8mb4 |  45 | Yes     | Yes      |       1 |
| utf8mb4_bin            | utf8mb4 |  46 |         | Yes      |       1 |
| utf8mb4_unicode_ci     | utf8mb4 | 224 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_icelandic_ci   | utf8mb4 | 225 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_latvian_ci     | utf8mb4 | 226 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_romanian_ci    | utf8mb4 | 227 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_slovenian_ci   | utf8mb4 | 228 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_polish_ci      | utf8mb4 | 229 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_estonian_ci    | utf8mb4 | 230 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_spanish_ci     | utf8mb4 | 231 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_swedish_ci     | utf8mb4 | 232 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_turkish_ci     | utf8mb4 | 233 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_czech_ci       | utf8mb4 | 234 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_danish_ci      | utf8mb4 | 235 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_lithuanian_ci  | utf8mb4 | 236 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_slovak_ci      | utf8mb4 | 237 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_spanish2_ci    | utf8mb4 | 238 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_roman_ci       | utf8mb4 | 239 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_persian_ci     | utf8mb4 | 240 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_esperanto_ci   | utf8mb4 | 241 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_hungarian_ci   | utf8mb4 | 242 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_sinhala_ci     | utf8mb4 | 243 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_german2_ci     | utf8mb4 | 244 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_croatian_ci    | utf8mb4 | 245 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci | utf8mb4 | 246 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8mb4_vietnamese_ci  | utf8mb4 | 247 |         | Yes      |       8 |
+------------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+
26 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` is #246; it was introduced in MySQL 5.6.  Hence, it may have gotten in to MariaDB 10.0, but I am not sure.

Are you mixing versions when doing `mysqldump`?  Or maybe during the load?  Please spell out the version that you dumped from, the version of `mysqldump` and the version you are loading into.

Comment: actually versions are not the same. But
`skip-grant-tables ` ,
`innodb_force_recovery = 3` ,
`innodb_purge_threads=0
`
in /etc/my.cnf has solved my problem.